# Jquery regular expression to exclude '/' in .replace()

Tags: jquery

I have a menu I would like to add a class 'active' to it, if it meets certain conditions in the URL.

This would allow me to style the menu item that correlates to the page the user is on.

The class is being added by jquery:

```
$(function () {
    setNavigation();
});

function setNavigation() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);

    $(".nav a").each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }
    });
}
```

(The fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/fc8fdv4a/)

The problem, is regardless of what the page/url is, its applying the active class to my homepage menu item  `<a href="/">Home</a>` as well as the page the user is on.

I can get round this by sepcifying the full URL such as `<a href="example.com">Home</a>`.

But for consistency I don't wish to be hard coding my domain into my menu items.

Would anyone mind shedding some light and explaining whats going wrong?

For clarification, I can get the script to function as expected, if I specify the whole address i.e.

`<a href="example.com">Home</a>`

but not if i specify as:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what your question actually is.  Please explain precisely what your code is supposed to do, and in what way it is failing to do it.

Comment: If it's the slash at the beginning that's the problem, can't you just do this? `path.substring(1, href.length)`

Comment: also, jsfiddle is not really compatible with this because there's no way to get the `#` anchors work.

Comment: @Alnitak I have updated my answer, I hope it clarifies my issue?

Comment: I can provide a link to a live example on my site. But I dont think that is allowed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

`if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {...}`

That will always match '/', because the href.length is 1, and the substring is therefore '/'.

What about just

`if (path == href) {...}`

instead? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the substring.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense, but the answer you have provided stops the function working at all? Should I approach this totally different?

Comment: with the sub string I'm trying to allow the script to function correctly if the path is say, example.com/about/notes. The about is selected and active applied to "about" in the menu. Not 'notes'.